# reduxtoolkit error api not working when i call on action

Tags: reactjs

**      I'm newbie to use reduxtoolkit any one can tell me what issue ? Is problem with toolkit? **

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ohy5b.png)

[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B69oF.png)

```
export const getUser = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({
      type: "GET_USER_REQUEST",
    });

    const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/v1/user`);

    dispatch({
      type: "GET_USER_SUCCESS",
      payload: data.user,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: "GET_USER_FAILURE",
      payload: error.response.data.message,
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: can you pls show your reducer component.

Comment: `import { createReducer } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
    loading:true,
}

export const userReducer = createReducer({initialState},{
    GET_USER_REQUEST:(state)=>{
        state.loading = true;
    },
    GET_USER_SUCCESS:(state, action)=>{
        state.loading = false;
        state.user = action.payload;
    },
    GET_USER_FAILure:(state, action)=>{
        state.loading = false;
        state.error = action.payload;
    },
}) `

Answer (score 0):

Check the Counter App which I developed using ReduxToolkit
[Counter App] - https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-toolkit-b2wqo8?file=/src/redux/counter.js:307-312

Answer (score 0):

This is basically how you do it in redux-toolkit:

[image]

You can dispatch action from the desired component by:

```
dispatch(appTransportRequest(eventId));
```